# Como acceder a Transmission fuera de la red local?

Tags: ubuntu, puertos

Tengo una Orange Pi Zero con Armbian, y me gustaria acceder al Transmission que tengo instalado desde cualquier otro dispositivo fuera de la red local, conozco la ip externa del dispositivo (no entiendo porque cambia siempre, me gustaria obtener una explicacion, y saber como dejarla fija a poder ser). Tengo añadido en el router los puertos a abrir (51413 y 9091) pero no consigo conectarme, tengo configurado el settings.json que me pille cualquier ip: whitelist=127.0.0.1,*.*.*.*

Sigo sin poder acceder externamente desde mi movil (por ejemplo) usando datos, no entiendo mucho del tema, se que tengo "iptables" desconectado.

Como saber con certeza que puertos estan abiertos y que pasos son los que me faltan? Muchas gracias

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La IP publica cambia porque las compañías de telefonía pueden usar la misma para varios usuarios que no se conecten simultáneamente. Si quieres sea fija tienes que pagar un extra para que te guarden siempre la misma. 
En armbian y GNU/Linux en general es bastante fácil usar un servicio como https://www.duckdns.org/ que te permite enlazar un nombre de dominio fijo con una IP dinámica.
En el router además de abrir los puertos tienes que redirigirlos. O sea, el puerto externo o WAN o algo así del 9091 lo rediriges a la IP interna fija de tu Orange Pi y al mismo puerto.